# regexp to following strings

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table "SomeTableName" with 2 columns:

1) WholeString

2) TSP

In "WholeString" column I can get 2 types of strings:

1) http://ads.jdtracker.com/?a=10515&c=19163&tsp=2974&s1=39827&s2=&s3=93885&s4=&s5=

2) TSP_2974_CTV_18933_HotGamesOnYourMobile

I have to create trigger to fill "TSP" column from "WholeString"

"2974" - is value that I have to put in TSP column.

My try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SomeTriggerName
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON SomeTableName
  FOR EACH ROW

IF substr(WholeString, 1, [7]) = N'http://'
    NEW.TSP:=REGEXP_SUBSTR(WholeString, 'SomeRegexp')
IF substr(WholeString, 1, [4]) = N'TSP_'
    NEW.TSP:=REGEXP_SUBSTR(WholeString, '(?<=(tsp=|TSP_))\d{4}')
```

Comment: with regexp you can match it with something like this `(TSP_|tsp=)[:digit:]{1,8}&`. then you can get the number out of the matched value.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any trigger code will do, just show that you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sometriggername
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON sometablename FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  :new.tsp := regexp_substr(:new.wholestring, '(tsp=|TSP_)(\d+)',1,1,'c',2);
END sometriggername;
```

The regex searches for either `tsp=` or `TSP_`, followed by one or more digits. And you want only the digits in the second set of brackets reported, hence the `1,1,'c',2` bit.

Answer (score 1):

Tested here http://blog.logiclabz.com/tools/online-regex-checker.aspx:

```
(?<=(tsp=|TSP_))\d{4}
```

Comment: This won't work on Oracle, it only uses a limited sub-set; the positive look-behind isn't supported.